# HTXM HX-trigger

Tags: go, htmx

I am trying to trigger a get for a table based on a response header

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tasks</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Complete</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todo-table" hx-get="http://localhost:8081/data" hx-trigger="todoAdded from:body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
func SubmitTodo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Header.Add(w.Header(), "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
    http.Header.Add(w.Header(), "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    http.Header.Add(w.Header(), "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    // Get the value from the form field
    value := r.FormValue("todo")
    if value == "" {
        return
    }

    todoList = append(todoList, todoTask{Task: value, Done: false, InputtedDate: time.Now()})
    fmt.Println(value)

    w.Header().Set("HX-Trigger", "todoAdded")

    // Respond with an "ok" message and set the HX-Trigger header
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("ok"))
}
```

I can see the header is set in the response but no get event is fired. If I replace "todoAdded" with "load" the get request does fire.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is that you are submitting a form, not through AJAX, but with a full page submit. I believe that the HX-Trigger header will then not be acted upon. Try adding [hx-boost](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-boost/) to the form in order to turn the submit into an htmx AJAX request and see if the header then works.

The docs for the [HX-Trigger](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) response headers says:

> These response headers can be used to trigger client side actions on the target element within a response to htmx.

If you are doing a normal form submit, then you are adding the header to a response to the page, not a response to htmx.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make a difference

Comment: In the browser's network tab, can you see the request header `HX-Request` for the submit and can you see the `HX-Trigger` header for the response?

Comment: If you aren't returning any HTML on the submit, then the htmx docs does [suggest](https://htmx.org/docs/#requests) using `204 - No Content` for your status code.

Comment: yes I can see the header

Comment: The respective headers for both the request and the response?